# SSIS C# Script Task Opens Excel Process, but not Application

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a simple main method here to open an Excel workbook. However, when I execute the script task in SSIS, a background EXCEL.exe process runs that I can see in the task manager, but an Excel window does not open. That said, **this script task works on other machines, but not this machine.** This makes me think I'm missing an install of some kind.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
public void Main()
    {

        try
        {
            string mySheet = @"C:\\Users\\dwh002\\Documents\\ZIP_COUNTY_032017.xlsx";
            var excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
            excelApplication.Visible = true;
            var workbooks = excelApplication.Workbooks;
            var workbook = workbooks.Open(mySheet);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Comment: is the SSIS package run as a system account? (/ configured differently on other machines)

Comment: Does your machine have installed one of the following drivers? AccessDatabaseEngine.exe or AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe   The first is for 32-bit.

Comment: Yes, the 32 bit version of Access Database engine is installed. Though I'm running Excel 2016 64 bit.

Comment: Is the 32 bit version of the Access Database engine also running on the other machines where the Excel window opens?  Or are they applying the 64-bit version?